# Git rebase in source tree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I’m just wondering that can I  rebase remote branch to another remote branch through SourceTree ?

Now I’m using git command line to handle this.
If SourceTree could be possible,it will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rebase at least local branches with SourceTree, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39929429/6309).

Sp make sure your [remote branches have a local branch name](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-sourcetree-branches-to-merge-an-update-732268925.html), do your rebase, and then push back (with a [`push --force` in SourceTree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51869863/6309))